# Is there anything to do with cursed items?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

An Anvil of Krong cursed my weapon. Is there anything to do to undo this, or should I just get rid of this item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to undo either the negative or the positive effects of an Anvil of Krong's enchantment.

As explained by [DredmorWiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Anvil_of_Krong) you have a 5/7 chance of gaining a positive enchantment, and a 2/7 chance of gaining a negative enchantment (except the first use that is always positive)

Cursed weapons can be sold to Brax or thrown into Lutefisk Cube.

I suggest you to always enchant something that you can replace with another, similar item in your inventory, in case Krong is angry with you.

Comment: If you're an archaeologist you can reroll them with This Translation Is All Wrong!; usually you can get the curse to affect a stat you don't care about anyway. Of course, if you have a weapon that's blessed 4 times and cursed once, you can probably keep using it, it's still good.

Answer (score 0):

From this [discussion board](http://www.onrpg.com/boards/184360.html):

> One important tip I can give everyone is watch out for cursed traps and monsters, I had to learn the hard way that they can give permanent negative stats on your equipment, ruined four weapons before I figured out what was causing it, freaking removed the regen I had on one of my swords so I was pissed. The items can be turned to unusable unless you have the skill This Translation is All Wrong! but even then that skill is likely to just re-roll other negative effects rather than remove them.